# R, classification, variables input as a group

Tags: r, classification

How do I classify variables in R when the classifying output is known only for a group of variables? Think of this as being similar to the 'Mastermind' board game.

Or, here is a concrete example I'm working on: a person eats different types of food on different days, and she either has an allergic reaction (to something she ate that day), or she does not. These data are available for a number of days. What is the person allergic to?

With real data, you cannot do simple elimination (all foods she ate on days with no reaction are fine), because there will be false positives and false negatives in the data. A probabilistic approach is needed (99% allergic to spinach, 20% allergic to mint, etc.).

Comment: Welcome to SO :)... It's a good idea to read through the [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guide before asking. Can you provide a small dataset for us to look at? Also include what you've tried, and your expected output to give us a better idea of what you're talking about.

Answer (score 1):

This is really more of a Statistics 101 question and thus better suited for stats.stackexchange.com but I will handle it.

The answer to your food analogy example is to use something like

- `lm()` # for linear models (least squares), univariate or multivariate
- `glm()` # generalized linear models (note: despite the name you can use these 2 for non-linear models as well, like polynomial regression)
- `nnet` #basic neural networks and
- `randomForest()`
- the package `caret` has over 100 classification models

and etc, etc. There are hundreds if not thousands of probabilistic approaches you could take. You can use normal equations, gradient descent, etc, etc. The possibilities are practically endless.

This should get you started:

https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/MachineLearning.html

https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Multivariate.html

http://blog.revolutionanalytics.com/2012/08/cheat-sheet-for-prediction-and-classification-models-in-r.html

I'm sorry but I've never heard of 'Mastermind'.